# dataTable no checking in second page

Tags: datatable

I have a problem with datatable pages. After the data.datatable I manage the checks with a for loop for all the elements to which I have to import the check to true.
However, all elements of the second page are not seen. It's as if I can only work on the page I see and the other doesn't exist. Indeed if I go from the Chrome console and search for $('#ck_252').prop("checked"); (present on page no.2 is undefined

```
$('#listaVLT2').DataTable({
            'responsive': true,
            data: data.data,
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'app_id',
                    "title": "Disponibile ",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return type === 'display'
                            ? '<input type=\'checkbox\' id="ck_' + data + '"></input>'
                            : data;
                    },

                },
                {
                    data: 'app_id',
                    "title": "Gioco Installato",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return type === 'display'
                            ? '<input type=\'checkbox\' id="ck_i' + data + '"></input>'
                            : data;
                    },

                },
                {
                    data: 'app_id',
                    "title": "Gioco Abilitato",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return type === 'display'
                            ? '<input type=\'checkbox\' id="ck_e' + data + '"></input>'
                            : data;
                    },

                },
                { data: 'app_id', "title": "App ID" },
                { data: 'app_macaddress', "title": "Macaddress" },
            ],
        });
    } else {
        alert('errore:' + data.message);
    }

for (var i = 0; i < listVltGame.length; i++) {

        console.log("check per il gioco  " + listVltGame[i].idGame);
        console.log("e VLT  " + listVltGame[i].idVlt);

        if (listVltGame[i].available == "true") {
            console.log('#ck_' + listVltGame[i].idVlt + "    true");
            $('#ck_' + listVltGame[i].idVlt).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            console.log('#ck_' + listVltGame[i].idVlt + "    false");
            $('#ck_' + listVltGame[i].idVlt).prop("checked", false);
        }

        if (listVltGame[i].installed == "true") {
            console.log('#ck_i' + listVltGame[i].idVlt + "    true");
            $('#ck_i' + listVltGame[i].idVlt).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            console.log('#ck_i' + listVltGame[i].idVlt + "    false");
            $('#ck_i' + listVltGame[i].idVlt).prop("checked", false);
        }

        if (listVltGame[i].enable == "true") {
            console.log('#ck_e' + listVltGame[i].idVlt + "    true");
            $('#ck_e' + listVltGame[i].idVlt).prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            console.log('#ck_e' + listVltGame[i].idVlt + "    false");
            $('#ck_e' + listVltGame[i].idVlt).prop("checked", false);
        }

    }

    $('#ck_252').prop("checked", true);
    console.log('#ck_252   true');
    $('#ck_i252').prop("checked", false);
    console.log('#ck_i252   false');
    $('#ck_e252').prop("checked", false);
    console.log('#ck_e252   false');
    $('#ck_254').prop("checked", true);
    console.log('#ck_254   true');
    $('#ck_i254').prop("checked", false);
    console.log('#ck_i254   false');
    $('#ck_e254').prop("checked", false);
    console.log('#ck_e254   false');
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution to display the checks by calling the function for the new page.

```
    $('.pagination').on( 'click', function () {

    console.log("refresh check");
    
    checking (listVltGame);

} );
```

however, I would need to save any changes made to the page before changing it.
If I try to save them in this function the page that has been left the data are no longer visible.